# Automated Login JS rejecting data

Tags: javascript, jquery, authentication

I'm making a script, that logins automatically when the login page loads.
It was supposed to be simple and easy, because it worked on all the other pages.
The script sets the values of email and password input fields and when it clicks the "Log in" button or when I click it, it seems that it just resets the form.

- If I run this function in a loop, it constantly fills up the input
  fields and on the button click they keep resetting.
- If I click anywhere on the page physically with a mouse, while loop is active, it logs me in successfully

Note: When I run the same code in  Chrome console, it works.

[image]
The code is quite simple :

```
window.location.href.includes("logon")?logIn():null;
const logIn = () =>{
    let username = $("input[name=email]")[0];
    let password = $("input[name=password]")[0]; .
    username.value = "email@gmail.com";
    password.value = "password";
    $(".logon-view__form-button")[0].click();
};
```

Comment: Have you checked what you have in `$(".logon-view__form-button")[0]`? P.S. Synthetic events without preceding user generated event may be ignored by browsers.

Comment: Also, you could try to trigger `submit` event on your form directly https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit

Comment: @Sergey
`<button class="button logon-view__form-button"><span>LOG IN</span></button>`

{className: "button logon-view__form-button", children: {…}}
children:
$$typeof: Symbol(react.element)
key: null
props:
bundle: "shared.common"
name: "login-link"
__proto__: Object
ref: null
type: ƒ (e)
_owner: null
__proto__: Object
className: "button logon-view__form-button"
__proto__: Object

Comment: I've tried this :
`let form = $(".logon-view__form")[0];
form.submit();`
and I received this error >
logon:1 POST https://www.example.com/en/logon 404

Comment: How are your submits handled? By button `click` event? Looks like your form `submit` event isn't handled by JS.

Comment: Have you tried delaying your function execution?

Comment: @Sergey 
Yes I have tried with setTimeout, but no change. What's driving me crazy is that everything works if I run inside the console or if I click physically anywhere on the page.